# Strip prepended and appended text from outside XML

Tags: php, xml

We have a PHP XML RPC we make to a third party and they are having issues with returning additional text outside the XML body like

```
133
<Envelope>
<Body>
<RESULT>
<SUCCESS>true</SUCCESS>
<SESSIONID>99B153C1DFA889C34213B</SESSIONID>
<ORGANIZATION_ID>f528764d624db129b32c21fbca0cb8d6</ORGANIZATION_ID>
<SESSION_ENCODING>;jsessionid=99B153C1DFA889C34213B</SESSION_ENCODING>
</RESULT>
</Body>
</Envelope>

0
```

The additional text varies and is not always numeric.  Their staff are working on the issue but in the interim it would be great if using PHP I could cleanly eliminate everything in their response outside the `<Envelope></Envelope>`.

Anyone have a tip for me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For example:

```
<?php

$xml = '133
<Envelope>
<Body>
<RESULT>
<SUCCESS>true</SUCCESS>
<SESSIONID>99B153C1DFA889C34213B</SESSIONID>
<ORGANIZATION_ID>f528764d624db129b32c21fbca0cb8d6</ORGANIZATION_ID>
<SESSION_ENCODING>;jsessionid=99B153C1DFA889C34213B</SESSION_ENCODING>
</RESULT>
</Body>
</Envelope>

0';

$open_tag = '<Envelope>';
$close_tag = '</Envelope>';

$start_index = strpos($xml,$open_tag);
$length = strpos($xml, $close_tag) - $start_index + strlen($close_tag);
$clean_xml = substr($xml, $start_index, $length);

echo $clean_xml;

echo "\r\n";
```

Other solution, inline but way less elegant:

```
$clean_xml = $open_tag . reset(explode($close_tag,end(explode($open_tag,$xml)))) . $close_tag;

echo $clean_xml;

echo "\r\n";
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$xml = preg_replace('~^.*(<Envelope>.+?</Envelope>).*$~si', '$1', $xml);
```

**Try this one.** The lazy version :)

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of approaches.  You could use `preg_match` and a regular expression to get to the data, or simple string matching.  Since you have a well-defined start and end-point, I would probably opt for the string matching.  Simply, read the entire response into a string.  use `strpos` to find the location of `<Envelope>` and `</Envelope>`. The just use `substr` to extract the string between the two positions (note you will need to add 11 to the location of the closing tag to include the closing tag in the extracted string.